# sfdisk given size exceeds max allowable

Tags: partition, fdisk

Hello i have a failed driver in a raid so i had to replace it with a new hard disk. The problem is that although both hard disk are Seagate 1TB they differ slightly in size

```
# sfdisk -s
/dev/sda: 976762584
/dev/sdb: 976761527
```

and when i try to use sfdisk to copy the partition table i get:

```
# sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/sdb: 121601 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track

sfdisk: ERROR: sector 0 does not have an msdos signature
 /dev/sdb: unrecognized partition table type
Old situation:
No partitions found
Warning: given size (15718400) exceeds max allowable size (15717743)

sfdisk: bad input
```

I searched google but didn't find a complete solution.

Any insight on how can i make it to work is appreciated

Comment: Whoever built that RAID array in the first place needs a smacking. Why would any sane person create a 2.00041 TB array, thus requiring a 1.0002 TB drive?! I guess you can get a 1.5TB replacement.

Comment: /dev/sda1 actualy has 2 partitions like this:/dev/sda1   *        2048  1937805311   968901632   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2      1937805312  1953523711     7859200   fd  Linux raid autodetect i was hoping i could make the swap partition smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Either you'll have to get a disk that's at least as large as the other one or you'll have to resize the RAID, which is a somewhat involved process.

What I would do is to just start over, create a new RAID with one missing disk on the new, smaller drive, copy the data over and then add the old drive to that array.

Of course, make sure you have a backup first.